# Puppet yum repo - Pull down 2.7.x vs 3.0.x

Tags: centos, yum, puppet, puppetmaster

So a few weeks ago I started on the path to using puppet to automate all the configs/services. At the time I was using the EPEL repo, which installed version 2.6.x. After some reading I was trying to gain access to the `flatten` method available via the puppet stdlib, and thought it was available by default in the newer 2.7.x version. So I added a puppet repo with the following settings:

```
[puppetlabs]
name=Puppet Labs Packages
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/$releasever/products/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
```

The problem with this, is it installed v3.0.x instead of 2.7.x. And apparently 3.0.x is a major upgrade which was released only a few weeks ago. Obviously I would prefer to use the 2.7.x for the next few months while PuppetLabs fix any defects which will inevitably arise after a major version.

So my question is, what setting can I add to the puppet repo config to pull down only the 2.7.x branch and not the 3.0.x branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the yum-versionlock plugin to lock the package version to what you want:

```
yum install yum-versionlock
```

To continue:

#### If you have already installed puppet

Now edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/versionlock.list` and specify the version you want:

```
puppet 2.7.19
puppet-server 2.7.19
```

Finally install it. Depending on your current situation, use only one of:

```
yum upgrade puppet
yum downgrade puppet
yum distro-sync
```

#### If you have not already installed puppet

Install a specific version of puppet:

```
yum install puppet-2.7.19
yum install puppet-server-2.7.19
```

Lock the package version to the currently installed version:

```
yum versionlock puppet
yum versionlock puppet-server
```