# Yum install php-pecl-memcached - No package found (Have epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm)

Tags: ssh, memcached

I believed I've downloaded and updated the EPEL rpm but I can't install php-pecl-memcached..
I'm very new to this, any help is appreciated.

```
#rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm warning: epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID
0608b895: NOKEY Preparing...               
########################################### [100%]
        package epel-release-6-8.noarch is already installed

# yum update Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base: mirror.us.leaseweb.net  * epel:
mirror.symnds.com  * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com  * updates:
mirror.vcu.edu Setting up Update Process No Packages marked for Update


#yum install php-pecl-memcached Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base:
mirror.us.leaseweb.net  * epel: mirror.symnds.com  * extras:
mirror.ash.fastserv.com  * updates: mirror.vcu.edu Setting up Install
Process No package php-pecl-memcached available. Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: do a `yum list all | grep php-pecl-memcached` to see if it's available.

Comment: nothing appeared.

Comment: Can you please try this command `# yum list | grep -i php | grep -i pecl | grep -i memcache` and give me the output

Comment: no output again

Comment: That means that the yum repos you have installed do not list this package as being available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have almost certainly mistakenly excluded some packages with yum's `exclude` option in your `yum.conf` or a file which it includes. For instance you may have:

```
exclude=php*
```

This would prevent any package whose name begins with PHP from ever being shown to you.

To fix the problem, remove the exclusion from your yum configuration.

(This was probably done as a misguided attempt to version-lock the PHP packages. [Use the yum versionlock plugin](https://serverfault.com/a/440582/126632) to accomplish this instead.)

Comment: Thank you! Removed php exlusion and it works! I'm unsure why php was excluded since I didn't do any modifications to the file.  Nonetheless it works now. TY Happy Holidays everyone

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [@Michael Hamptons answer](https://serverfault.com/a/461594/2518). You could have debugged this issue like this as well.

**1.** First confirm same system as OP

```
% uname -a
Linux data01 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
% cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
```

**2.** Show `yum` cmds when there is no `exclude=php*` present in `/etc/yum.conf`

```
% repoquery *pecl* --location
http://eq-centosrepo.hopto.org/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
http://eq-centosrepo.hopto.org/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/php-pecl-apc-devel-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
http://eq-centosrepo.hopto.org/6.3/os/x86_64/Packages/php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

**3.** Show repos

```
% yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * extras: mirror.anl.gov
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
repo id                                                  repo name                                                            status
base                                                     CentOS-6 - Base                                                      6,346
extras                                                   CentOS-6 - Extras                                                       17
updates                                                  CentOS-6 - Updates                                                   1,048
repolist: 7,411
```

**4.** Add an `exclude=php*` to `/etc/yum.conf`

```
% vim /etc/yum.conf
...
...
exclude=php*
...
```

**5.** Confirm **php*** packages are excluded

```
# with repoquery

% repoquery *pecl* --location
% 

# with yum

% yum list all php-pecl*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * extras: mirror.anl.gov
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

**6.** Tell yum to ignore the excludes using `--disableexcludes=all` switch

```
% yum list all php-pecl* --disableexcludes=all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: yum.singlehop.com
 * extras: mirror.anl.gov
 * updates: mirrors.seas.harvard.edu
Available Packages
php-pecl-apc.x86_64                                                    3.1.9-2.el6                                              base
php-pecl-apc-devel.x86_64                                              3.1.9-2.el6                                              base
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64                                               3.0.5-4.el6                                              base
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check to see if you have the package installed already...

```
# yum list installed php-pecl-memcached.x86_64
```

or

```
# rpm -qi php-pecl-memcached
```

That will give you an indication of the current state of the system. From here, it looks like you already have this installed... but those two commands will help you check for sure.

-- edit --

The `yum repolist` output shows the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository enabled, as well as the [Powerstack repo](http://wiki.powerstack.org/PowerStack). These two have similar packages. In Powerstack, which is probably handling your PHP and Apache, you need to:

`yum install php-pecl-memcache`

The package has a slightly different name than in EPEL. Try that.

Comment: Packages aren't installed.
First output Error: No matching Packages to list
Second output package php-pecl-memcached is not installed
thanks!

Comment: Run a `yum clean all` and try `yum install php-pecl-memcached` again.

Comment: cleaned successfully, tried again to install but end result was
`Setting up Install Process
No package php-pecl-memcached available.
Error: Nothing to do`

Comment: What OS and version are you using?

Comment: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Comment: `yum repolist` outputs what?

Comment: 'base            CentOS-6 - Base                                        5,980+366  |
epel            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64       6,907+1,351  |
extras          CentOS-6 - Extras                                             17  |
powerstack      PowerStack for CentOS 6                                    31+53   |
updates         CentOS-6 - Updates                                        989+59   |
repolist: 13,924'

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I've actually tried that but nothing shows up either. `No package php-pecl-memcache available.
Error: Nothing to do`