# yum not showing any updated package

Tags: yum, centos6, update

I have a `CentOS 6.3` machine. I'm running `yum update` but it doesn't show any updated package. I have already tried `yum clean all` and `yum clean expire-cache`. Any help will be really appreciated.

```
[root@www1 yum.repos.d]# yum list update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.xmission.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: mirrors.xmission.com
 * updates: mirrors.xmission.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

P.S. I have `epel` installed as well, and I was playing with that while ago. I'm thinking that I might screw up something that day, probably ...

P.P.S. I've also tried to use `baseurl` instead of `mirrorlist`, again no success at all ...

**Update**

I had this line in my `yum.conf` which was supposed to keep the `postfix` package for manual updates. I just comment that out and everything seems fine now. Could anybody explain why?

```
exclude=postfix*
```

**Answer**

I was trying to do `yum list update` which was wrong! I should write `updates` not `update`. Actually the `yum update` works well, however I thought if `yum list update` is not working, then `yum update` will not work as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yum install php-pecl-memcached - No package found (Have epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm)](http://serverfault.com/questions/461583/yum-install-php-pecl-memcached-no-package-found-have-epel-release-6-8-noarch)

Comment: @MichaelHampton but it's not only a package, it's not showing anything. I'll check the configuration again ...

Comment: It looks like the same problem, and the solution is the same.

Comment: @MichaelHampton wow, please take a look at my update, do you have any idea why it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error: No matching Packages to list

It means that there is no package named... "update". The right command is:

```
yum list updates
```

[**`man yum`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum):

```
LIST OPTIONS
       The  following are the ways which you can invoke yum in list mode.  
    Note that all list commands include information on the version of the package.    

       yum list updates [glob_exp1] [...]
              List all packages with updates available in the yum repositories.
```